# How to insert multiple object data to div class or img source with javascript code?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 table from database, "event participant" and "event participant media".

I've export the data from both tables to javascript variables and the results are as below

```
var participant_obj = [ // from event_participant

{"0":"13","id":"13","1":"3","eventid":"3","2":"PT. JTour Kreatif","name":"PT. JTour Kreatif",
"3":"","profilepic":"","4":"","idnumber":"","5":"","birthplace":"","6":"0000-00-00",
"birthdate":"00000000","7":"mymail@abc.com","email":"mymail@abc.com","8":"qwert.com",
"website":"qwert.com","9":"1234567890","phone":"1234567890","10":"qwert","sosmed":"qwert",
"11":"qwert","cp_note":"qwert","12":"","genre":"","13":"","trademark":"",
"14":"perjalanan & liburan","business":"perjalanan & liburan","15":"up to 10%",
"sale":"up to 10%","16":"","sale_note":"","17":"","community":"",
"18":"Vestibulum nec condimentum metus. Vestibulum vel mattis sapien, venenatis tincidunt 
odio.","description":"Vestibulum nec condimentum metus. Vestibulum vel mattis sapien,
venenatis tincidunt odio.","19":"2016-08-05 08:15:12","created_at":"2016-08-05 08:15:12",
"20":"2016-08-12 21:11:19","updated_at":"2016-08-12 21:11:19"},


{"0":"17","id":"17","1":"3","eventid":"3","2":"&#34pakaian &#39;batman&#39; super&#34",
"name":"&#34pakaian &#39;batman&#39; super&#34","3":"","profilepic":"","4":"","idnumber":"",
"5":"","birthplace":"","6":"0000-00-00","birthdate":"0000-00-00","7":"sdfhsd@sdg",
"email":"sdfhsd@sdg.com","8":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com",
"website":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com","9":"2346234632","phone":"2346234632","10":"sdfh",
"sosmed":"sdfh","11":"abcd","cp_note":"abcd","12":"","genre":"","13":"","trademark":"",
"14":"pakaian","business":"pakaian","15":"kosong","sale":"kosong","16":"","sale_note":"",
"17":"","community":"","18":"sdfhsdfh","description":"sdfhsdfh","19":"2016-09-01 07:56:47",
"created_at":"2016-09-01 07:56:47","20":"2016-09-03 16:57:12",
"updated_at":"2016-09-03 16:57:12"}}

];
```

and

```
var participant_media   = [ // from event_participant_media

{"0":"27","id":"27","1":"13","participantid":"13","2":null,"type":null,"3":"image",
"format":"image","4":"DSCN6741.JPG","link":"DSCN6741.JPG","5":"2016-09-03 09:46:25",
"created_at":"2016-09-03 09:46:25","6":"2016-09-03 14:46:25",
"updated_at":"2016-09-03 14:46:25"},

{"0":"28","id":"28","1":"13","participantid":"13","2":null,"type":null,"3":"image",
"format":"image","4":"DSCN6742.JPG","link":"DSCN6742.JPG","5":"2016-09-03 09:46:43",
"created_at":"2016-09-03 09:46:43","6":"2016-09-03 14:46:43",
"updated_at":"2016-09-03 14:46:43"},

{"0":"29","id":"29","1":"17","participantid":"17","2":null,"type":null,"3":"image",
"format":"image","4":"20121001_202706.jpg","link":"20121001_202706.jpg",
"5":"2016-09-03 12:08:18","created_at":"2016-09-03 12:08:18","6":"2016-09-03 17:08:18",
"updated_at":"2016-09-03 17:08:18"},

{"0":"30","id":"30","1":"17","participantid":"17","2":null,"type":null,"3":"image",
"format":"image","4":"20150313_051134.jpg","link":"20150313_051134.jpg",
"5":"2016-09-03 12:08:45","created_at":"2016-09-03 12:08:45","6":"2016-09-03 17:08:45",
"updated_at":"2016-09-03 17:08:45"}

];
```

and then I insert object's name id 13 into html tag like this

```
var obj = _.find(participant_obj, function(obj){return obj.id == 13});
var name = obj['name'];
document.querySelector("div#dp_head h2").innerHTML = name;
```

so in HTML

```
<div id="dp_head">
  <h2>(result from participant id name)</h2>
</div>
```

its easy for me to input one object's name, but the problem is, each participant has two object images (as you can see in var participant_media). usually in php i will writing like this

```
<?php
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `event_participant_media` WHERE`participantid` = 13 AND `format` = 'image'"); 
while($s=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 
?>
   <div class="dp_media_img">
      <img src="<?php echo $s['link']; ?>" />
   </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

if tried this

```
var obj_media_img = _.find(participant_media, function(obj_media){return obj_media.participantid == participantid && obj_media.format == "image"});
var img_numbers = Object.keys(obj_media_img).length;
for(var i=0; i<img_numbers; i++){
    var images = obj_media_img[i]['link'];
    document.getElementsByClassName("dp_media_img")[i].document.querySelectorAll("div.dp_media_img img").src = "participant_media/"+images;
}
```

but not working. i have to insert images to

```
<div class="dp_media_img">
  <img src="<?php echo $s['link']; ?>" />
</div>
```

with javascript code

hope you can help me.

tq.

(sorry if there's a wrong word or grammar in my post)

Comment: I've changed your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag, and if I'm wrong, please let me know. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know absolutely nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem in the following line:
`document.querySelector("div#dp_head h2").innerHTML = name;`
The space between "div#dp_head h2" isn't a recognized method.  Also, the # character is sufficient for referencing the div by its id.  This should fix this error:

```
var x = document.getElementById('dp_head');
document.querySelector('h2').innerHTML = name;
```

Comment: that line for participant object. i need participant's image object

Comment: The query ```$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `event_participant_media` WHERE`participantid` = 13 AND `format` = 'image'");``` should have spaces and I don't think you need the backtics?  I have a system that required them for the column entries, but not since 2011?  Maybe no back tics on the column name too?
```$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `event_participant_media` WHERE participantid = 13 AND format = 'image'");```